# What's the difference between CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH

Tags: cmake

I have a difficult time in understanding the difference between CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH.

If I understand well, CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is the prefixed directory that will be installed. Therefore, if I use the following script for installation:

```
project(hello)
add_library(hello hello.h hello.cpp)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "c:/ABC/DEF")
INSTALL(TARGETS hello EXPORT hello_export
            RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
            LIBRARY DESTINATION bin
            ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
            FRAMEWORK DESTINATION bin
            INCLUDES  DESTINATION include
            )
```

Then the static library will be installed in C:/ABC/DEF/lib.

Then, my question is what's the point of using CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a system which supports paths of the form `c:/ABC/DEF` (i.e. Windows), none. Windows binaries don't have a notion of [*rpath*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath).

On systems which do have `DT_RPATH` and `DT_RUNPATH` (= those which use ELF binaries), the CMake variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` is used to set up the value of `DT_RPATH` (or `DT_RUNPATH`) tags which will be written into the binaries at installation.

Answer (score 8):

This is explained at [CMake RPATH handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).

On Unix systems, dynamic libraries are searched for in a system-defined list of directories. (`/etc/ld.so.conf` -- Windows does this [in its own way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28VS.85%29.aspx) that is so convoluted that it usually boils down to "just use `PATH`". )

If you install a library (like the one you just compiled) in a *custom* directory, not in that list, it will not be found if you run a dependent executable. `RPATH` is one way to fix this.

See the Wiki page linked above for details.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX determines a "root" for the installed location of headers, libraries, executables, and other resources.

On a system which does not support the notion of a "search hierachy" for dependencies, CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH is not used. However, on ELF-based systems (e.g. Linux) and Mach-based systems (e.g. macOS 10.5 and later) a set of additional locations to search can be set in executables and dynamic libraries (e.g. .so/.dylib files); this is the "Rpath" and you can set it during cmake's install phase, either for all targets by setting CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH or for individual targets by setting INSTALL_RPATH on that target.

Static libraries are not dynamic (obviously!) so, CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH has no utility at all for static libraries.

When installing dynamic objects, CMake will write the Rpath into the dynamic object provided CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH and CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH are both false. By default, the Rpath written will be set to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX followed by the library destination, e.g. CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/lib. On Linux systems, this would by default see an Rpath of /usr/local/lib written as Rpath.

You can examine the Rpath on Linux thus:

```
readelf -d libmylib.so
```

which produces something like:

```
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/usr/local/lib]
```

or on macOS:

```
otool -l libmylib.dylib | grep -A 2 LC_RPATH
```

which produces something like:

```
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 40
         path @loader_path/../Frameworks (offset 12)
```

To override the install Rpath you can set the variable CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH. E.g. on Linux:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN/../lib")
```

or on macOS:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path/../lib")
```